# STM32F4 HSE crystal

Tags: stm32, oscillator, surface-mount, crystal, routing

I'm trying to set up an HSE for my [STM32f4](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1848998.pdf), using [this](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1841779.pdf) crystal.
but there are 2 pins: OSC_IN and OSC_OUT, but my crystal only has one output.

What do I link OSC_IN and OUT to?
[image]

Comment: Try here http://stm32f4-discovery.com/

Comment: Why do you have that 15pF cap on the output of your oscillator?

Comment: The 15 pF is not needed since it is what the oscillator is capable of driving (15-50pF).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 'crystal' you are using is actually a complete oscillator module that generates a CMOS (digital) output pulse. The two pins on the STM32 are for when you are using a bare crystal and provide access points to the built-in oscillator circuit.

As you don't need to use this you can just connect the output from your oscillator to the OSC_IN pin and leave the OSC_OUT disconnected. Note that it is very important that you configure the chip to use an external clock - not the HSE oscillator - or it won't work properly.

Comment: In STs words it's commonly called HSE bypass.